# error in position of matching parentheses

Tags: php, algorithm

```
<?php
function find($text,$openpos)
{
  $closepos=$openpos;
  $counter=1;
  while($counter>0)
  {
    $c=$text[++$closepos];
    if($c=='(')
    {
      $counter++;
    }
    else if($c==')')
    {
      $counter--;
    }
  }
  return $closepos;
}
$c=find("(1+2*(5-2)/(3-1))","6");
echo $c;
?>
```

It shows the error

> "sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `(' sh: -c: line 0:`php main.php (1+2*(5-2)/(3-1)) 6'"

How to solve this?

Comment: I can see only one missed `$` here `else if(c==')')` `$c`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change this line:

```
else if(c==')')
```

To:

```
else if($c==')')
```

Comment: I ran your code after changing that line, and I got no error. It just gave an ouptut of 9 which corresponds to the closing parenthesis after your entry point of 6. If there's another error, it's not in the code you posted.

Comment: I just used it too. Like I said, it gives an output of 9 with no error.

Comment: Who downvoted my answer and why? The original question had a syntax error.